# Como Ordenar Registros Depois do Count

Tags: mysql

### Query

```
SET @ranking = 0;

SELECT
    @ranking := @ranking + 1 AS rank,
    `empresas`.`id`,
    `empresas`.`id` AS `id_empresa`,
    `empresas`.`id_marca`,
    `slug`,
    `slug_bairro`,
    `empresa_logins`.`nome`,
    `empresas`.`id_cidade`,
    `empresas`.`empresa`,
    COUNT(empresa_leads.id) AS qtd_leads
FROM
    `empresa_leads`
RIGHT JOIN `empresas` ON `empresas`.`id` = `empresa_leads`.`id_empresa`
LEFT JOIN `empresa_login_admins` ON `empresa_login_admins`.`id_empresa` = `empresas`.`id`
AND `empresa_login_admins`.`id_funcao` = 11
AND `empresa_login_admins`.`id_categoria` IS NULL
LEFT JOIN `empresa_logins` ON `empresa_logins`.`id` = `empresa_login_admins`.`id_empresa_login`
WHERE
    `empresa_leads`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
AND `empresas`.`id_marca` = 11
AND empresas.`estado` = 26
GROUP BY
    `empresas`.`id`
ORDER BY
    qtd_leads desc, rank
```

### Retorno

```
Rank                        Qtd_Leads
49        12291 12291 11       15
1         12243 12243 11       0
2         12244 12244 11       0
3         12245 12245 11       0
4         12246 12246 11       0
```

Eu preciso que o Ranking seja feito pela quantidade de leads. Quem tem mais, fique em primeiro. Mas ele me retorna com o número do Ranking errado.

Isso acontece porquê ele coloca o número antes de fazer o Count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT
        @ranking := @ranking + 1 AS rank,
        `empresas`.`id`,
        `empresas`.`id` AS `id_empresa`,
        `empresas`.`id_marca`,
        `slug`,
        `slug_bairro`,
        `empresa_logins`.`nome`,
        `empresas`.`id_cidade`,
        `empresas`.`empresa`,
        COUNT(empresa_leads.id) AS qtd_leads
    FROM
        `empresa_leads`
    RIGHT JOIN `empresas` ON `empresas`.`id` = `empresa_leads`.`id_empresa`
    LEFT JOIN `empresa_login_admins` ON `empresa_login_admins`.`id_empresa` = `empresas`.`id`
    AND `empresa_login_admins`.`id_funcao` = 11
    AND `empresa_login_admins`.`id_categoria` IS NULL
    LEFT JOIN `empresa_logins` ON `empresa_logins`.`id` = `empresa_login_admins`.`id_empresa_login`
    WHERE
        `empresa_leads`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    AND `empresas`.`id_marca` = 11
    AND empresas.`estado` = 26
    GROUP BY
        `empresas`.`id`
    ORDER BY
        qtd_leads desc
    ) AS results
    ORDER BY results.rank
```

Answer (score 1):

```
order by 1
 //se quiser ordenar por "rank"

ou 

order by 10
//se quiser ordenar por "qtd_leads"
```

Comment: Não ordena direito. Eu quero ordenar pela **qtd_leads** e depois **rank** para ficar certo.

Comment: podes recorer a subquery